# how can we pass more than one dataprovider in to a single Test

Tags: selenium, testng

I want to read data from an excel file having two sheet named as "LoginPo" and "LoginData". So how can i achieve this and use these two Data providers return value in my test like below.What will be the correct approach?Please help

```
@DataProvider(name="DP1")
public Object[][] createData1() throws Exception
{
Object[][] arr = getCSV("C://Users//purnendu_rath//Desktop//Login.csv","LoginPO");
    return arr;
}
@DataProvider(name="DP2")
public Object[][] createData() throws Exception
{
    Object[][] arr = getCSV("C://Users//purnendu_rath//Desktop//Login.csv","LoginData");
    return arr;
}
@Test(DataProvider="DP1","Dp2")
public void accountLogin(//pass teh value here of DP1 and DP2)
{
     //Coding for testcase
}
```

Comment: What is the returned content of `getCSV()` method?

Comment: Getcsv() returns the content of "LoginData" sheet(contains username and psw for 10 users) and  LoginPo sheet's returns login page's bject's property  value.i.e csspath value of all login window page object(like username filed,password field,submit button,cancel button etc.).